# How to install afc2add without using wi-fi in a jailbroken iPad 3 with 7.0.4?

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak

I have an iPad 3 and originally I had installed iOS 5.1.1. Then, I used the command "nvram wifiaddr=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" to change my mac address using the MobileTerminal, but I didn't realized I changed it to an invalid mac address. The first thing that happened was that after rebooting my device, it says that I have to connect my device to iTunes. After searching in google and testing all different methods to overcome this issue, none of them worked for me.

Then, I decided to update my iOS to 7.0.4 since I was running out of options. After I installed it, I noticed that my Wifi says N/A in the Settings/Info screen. Knowing this, search in the web and I later realized that the connect to iTunes error I was having was due to an invalid mac address that I had assigned.

Later, the jailbreak for iOS 7 came out and I was very happy since I thought that my problem was going to be solved. Guess what? It didn't. I now have cydia in my iPad 3 with iOS 7.0.4, but, in order to install mobileTerminal or openssh, I need to install afc2add in order to access the root folder of the device. But guess what? I can't. Why? Because I don't have internet because I don't have a valid mac address.

So, this is like a kind of a deadlock. I tried all methods I came think out. I tried to restore again my device back to iOS 5.1.1 since I have my shsh files, but unfortunely since its an A5 device, you can't do that as for now. I then try to install afc2add using a program called cyder from my computer, but guess what? I can't because I need afc2add in order to access my jailbroken device's root folder. I also tried sharing internet access using an iPhone 5's hotspot and my iPad, but since I don't have a valid mac address, it seems I can't receive anything from the internet. I know this because I did this same test with another iPad 3 with iOS 7.0.4 and a valid mac address and with this one it worked well.

So, I'm running out of options, what can I do? I guess I have to wait to either the A5 devices can be downgraded, a program that helps me install afc2add in my device or a jailbreak that already includes this for iOS 7. If you happen to know what to do, please let me know. Thanks!

---

**Edit**: I tried the latest version of iExplorer with not luck. Just in case, I also tried: iFunBox, iTools, PP Assistant, 91 Assistant, cyder and iSpirit. With iSpirit I can see the Cydia AutoInstall folder, but even if I upload deb files in there, since it says it's jailed, I don't think I'm uploading the files in the right place. I also tried creating the Cydia AutoInstall folder manually without any luck. I think as long as I can access the correct folder of where to put deb files for Cydia to install, that will also solve my problem. Thanks!

---

**Edit2**: I also tried Diskaid with no avail.

Comment: I don't know whether [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/features/mount-iphone-disk-mode-file-folder-access/) uses afc or not, but you might want to give it a try. Maybe you could be able to upload `afc2add` this way. You can also take a look at this: https://github.com/suzumura-ss/ruby-io-afc. I believe the AFC service is automatically running on iOS, you could play with symlinks to upload the `afc2add` binary in the right folder.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't knew you can use a library to access the root folder. I guess I will try that. The only thing is that I don't know anything about Ruby, but I guess I will have to learn about it. If I have more questions regarding ruby, I will open a different thread. For now, until I solve this, I will leave this thread open. Thanks and I will keep you updated.

Comment: In the end, I tried to install ruby, but I couldn't do it. So, I wasn't able to test this method. However, reading the descriptions of the person who did it, it says that it gives you access to the file system of the iDevice since he want to use it with FrankServer in order to do some testing, but it doesn't say anything regarding giving root access to the device, so I'm not sure if it will still worth giving it a shot.

Comment: Searching in google I found this:
http://instasign.uhelios.com/

It says that you can sign an ipa or deb file and install it normally as if installing an application downloaded from the Apple Store. However, it requires a valid Apple Developer certificate name and provisioning profile, which I don't have. Can someone with a Apple Developer Certificate confirm this for me? Maybe I can install the afc2add deb file this way. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to restore your device in DFU mode?  Don't use regular restore mode, don't restore your device from backup after installing iOS. Clean install in DFU mode. May be Wi-Fi MAC will be restored to it's default value as well.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps I followed:

- Create a `Packages.bz2` file which includes info of `afc2add` and `erica utilities`.
- Copy `Packages.bz2` and the 2 `.deb` files in some folder inside your *iDevice* (`Downloads`, `Books`, etc).
- Add a new source repo in Cydia: `file:///var/mobile/Media/Downloads`
- Just install `Erica Utilities` first and then `afc2add`

For a more detailed description, you can read my blog post:

[How to install afc2add and other packages without WiFi connection](http://blog.omederos.com/posts/2014/02/11/how-to-install-afc2add-and-other-packages-without-wifi-connection/)

Comment: I have to agree though as the author of afc2add I would have preferred suggesting IPhoneBrowser ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this! If you are curious how, take a look at this post:

http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/211048/how-to-install-afc2add-without-using-wi-fi-in-a-jailbroken-ipad-3-with-704

Thanks for all your help guys!